# Java: Implementação de lista duplamente encadeada (deque) com callback, generics, exception e lambda

Tags: java, lista, lista-encadeada

Estou fazendo a implementação em java, entretanto estou com alguns problemas de como integrar o generics e lambda no deque:

`Deque.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Deque {
    private Element head;
    private Element tail; 
    public Deque() {
        head = tail = null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null && tail == null;
    }
    public boolean isFull() {
        return false;
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> List() throws EmptyListException { //generics and exception
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();     
        if(head == null)
            throw new EmptyListException("The list is empty!");     
        else{
            Element elementFirst = getFirst();          
            while(elementFirst != null){
                int value = elementFirst.getValue(); 
                list.add(value);
                elementFirst = elementFirst.getNext();
            }
            return list;
        }       
    }
    public void addFirst(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Addited in first: " + o);
        Element e = new Element(o);
        e.setNext(head); 

        if(head != null) {
            head.setPrev(e);  
        }
        head = e; 
        if(tail == null) {
            tail = e; 
        }
    }
    public void addLast(Object o) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Addited in last: " + o);
        Element e = new Element(o);
        e.setPrev(tail); 

        if(tail != null) {
            tail.setNext(e);
        }
        tail = e;
        if(head == null) {
            head = e;
        }
    }
    public Object removeFirst() throws Exception {
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception ("The Queue is empty!");
        } else {
            Object o = head.getValue();
            head = head.getNext(); 
            if(head == null) { 
                tail = null;
            } else {
                head.setPrev(null); 
            }
            System.out.println("Removed in first: " + o);
            System.out.println("New head: " + head.getValue());
            return o;
        }
    }
    public Object removeLast() throws Exception {
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception ("The Queue is empty!");
        } else {
            Object o = tail.getValue();
            tail = tail.getPrev(); 
            if(tail == null) {
                head = null;
            } else {
                tail.setNext(null); 
            }
            System.out.println("Removed in last: " + o);
            System.out.println("New tail: " + tail.getValue());
            return o;
        }
    }
    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Start clear... ");
        while (!this.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                this.removeFirst();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End clear");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    public void listing() {
        Element e = head;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Start listing... ");
        while (e != null) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + e.getValue());
            e = e.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("End listing");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

`Element.java`:

```
public class Element {
    private Element next;
    private Element prev;
    private Object value;
    public Element (Object v) {
        value = v;
    }
    public void setNext(Element e) {
        this.next = e;
    }
    public Element getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setPrev(Element e) {
        this.prev = e;
    }
    public Element getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Object getValue() {
        if(value != null) {
            System.out.println("the value is null!");
            return false;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        Deque deque = new Deque(); 

        do{         
            System.out.println("Select the option\n 1->Add first:\n 2->Add last:\n3->List:\n 4->Remove first:\n 5->Remove last:\n 6->Clear:\n 7->Exit:\n");     
            option = scanner.next();            
            if(option == 1){
                System.out.println("Enter with the value: ");
                value = scanner.next();
                deque.addFirst(value);
            }               
            else if(option == 2){
                System.out.println("Enter with the value: ");
                value = scanner.next();
                deque.addLast(value);       
            }                   
            else if(option == 3){
                ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    myList = deque.List();
                    //deque.listing();
                } 
                catch (EmptyListException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }
            }
            else if(option == 4){
                deque.removeFirst();        
            }
            else if(option == 5){
                deque.removeLast(); 
            }
            else if(option == 6){
                deque.clear();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
            }
        }
        while(option != "7");
    }
}
```

Comment: Quais problemas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos começar com o `Element`:

```
public class Element<T> {
    private Element<T> next;
    private Element<T> prev;
    private T value;

    public Element(T v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public void setNext(Element<T> e) {
        this.next = e;
    }

    public Element<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setPrev(Element<T> e) {
        this.prev = e;
    }

    public Element<T> getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        /*if(value != null) {
            System.out.println("the value is null!");
            return false;
        }*/
        return value;
    }
}
```

Esse `return false;` do `getValue()` é nocivo. Ele te impede de usar tipos genéricos aí. Além disso, se o conteúdo do `Element` for `null`, que o método `getValue()` retorne esse `null`.

A classe `EmptyListException`:

```
public class EmptyListException extends Exception {
    public EmptyListException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Agora a classe `Deque`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deque<T> {
    private Element<T> head;
    private Element<T> tail; 

    public Deque() {
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null && tail == null;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return false;
    }

    public List<T> toList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();     
        Element<T> elementFirst = getFirst();          
        while (elementFirst != null) {
            T value = elementFirst.getValue(); 
            list.add(value);
            elementFirst = elementFirst.getNext();
        }
        return list;     
    }

    public void addFirst(T o) {
        System.out.println("Addited in first: " + o);
        Element<T> e = new Element<>(o);
        e.setNext(head); 

        if (head != null) {
            head.setPrev(e);  
        }
        head = e; 
        if (tail == null) {
            tail = e; 
        }
    }

    public void addLast(T o) {
        System.out.println("Addited in last: " + o);
        Element<T> e = new Element<>(o);
        e.setPrev(tail); 

        if (tail != null) {
            tail.setNext(e);
        }
        tail = e;
        if (head == null) {
            head = e;
        }
    }

    public T removeFirst() throws EmptyListException {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyListException("The deque is empty!");
        }
        T o = head.getValue();
        head = head.getNext(); 
        if (head == null) { 
            tail = null;
        } else {
            head.setPrev(null); 
        }
        System.out.println("Removed in first: " + o);
        System.out.println("New head: " + head.getValue());
        return o;
    }

    public T removeLast() throws EmptyListException {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyListException("The deque is empty!");
        }
        T o = tail.getValue();
        tail = tail.getPrev(); 
        if (tail == null) {
            head = null;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(null); 
        }
        System.out.println("Removed in last: " + o);
        System.out.println("New tail: " + tail.getValue());
        return o;
    }

    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Start clear... ");
        while (!this.isEmpty()) {
            this.removeFirst();
        }
        System.out.println("End clear");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void listing() {
        Element<T> e = head;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Start listing... ");
        while (e != null) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + e.getValue());
            e = e.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("End listing");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Aqui há várias coisas a se notar:

1. No método `List()` (que renomeeie para `toList()`) você usava `ArrayList<Integer>`. Isso daí presumia que o tipo do deque era `Integer` ao invés de `T`.
2. Usar `throws Exception` é uma má prática de programação, pois você deve declarar o lançamento de exceções específicas aso invés de exceções genéricas. Da mesma forma, `throw new Exception(...)` também é uma má prática pelo mesmo motivo. Ao usar `EmptyListException`, a exceção específica é declarada e lançada, ao invés da exceção genérica.
3. E terceiro que chamar o método `toList()` em um deque vazio não tem problema, o resultado será apenas uma lista vazia.
4. Não declare variáveis do tipo `ArrayList`. Embora você possa usar o construtor de `ArrayList`, o melhor é declarar o tipo da variável com `List` apenas. O motivo disso é que há um princípio de programação que diz para você codificar para uma interface (`List`) e não para uma implementação (`ArrayList`). Ao fazer isso, você poderá interoperar com outros tipos de listas (como `LinkedList` ou as listas retornadas por métodos como `Arrays.asList(...)`, `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` ou `List.of(...)`).

Finalmente, vamos ver o seu `Main`:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Deque<String> deque = new Deque<>();

        while (true) {         
            System.out.println("Select the option\n 1->Add first:\n 2->Add last:\n3->List:\n 4->Remove first:\n 5->Remove last:\n 6->Clear:\n 7->Exit:\n");
            String option = scanner.next();
            if ("1".equals(option)) {
                System.out.println("Enter with the value: ");
                value = scanner.next();
                deque.addFirst(value);
            } else if ("2".equals(option)) {
                System.out.println("Enter with the value: ");
                value = scanner.next();
                deque.addLast(value);
            } else if ("3".equals(option)) {
                List<String> myList = deque.toList();
                System.out.println(myList);
                deque.listing();
            } else if ("4".equals(option)) {
                try {
                    deque.removeFirst();
                } catch (EmptyListException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else if ("5".equals(option)) {
                try {
                    deque.removeLast();
                } catch (EmptyListException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else if ("6".equals(option)) {
                deque.clear();
            } else if ("7".equals(option)) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As observações aqui são as seguintes:

1. Você não tinha declarado a variável `option` adequadamente. O método `next()` do `Scanner` retorna `String`s, logo `option` seria do tipo `String`. Isso pode parecer meio estranho considerando que os valores esperados são 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 e 7. No entanto, isso permite que se você quiser trocar para A, B, C, D, E, F e G não tenha problemas. Até mesmo algo como Vermelho, Laranja, Amarelo, Verde, Azul, Anil e Violeta funcionaria.
2. Troquei o `do-while` para `while` para evitar que o `Invalid option` apareça quando o usuário quiser sair.
3. Não sei se o método `listing()` do seu `Deque` é uma boa ideia, vez que um `System.out.println(deque.toList())` já seria o suficiente.

Ah, finalmente, não existe nenhum lambda ou callback (ainda) no seu código.

Comment: Cá entre nós, com tanta classe de exceção nativa, você acha interessante se criar uma classe de exceção própria só pra ter uma classe com um nome próprio, com apenas 4 linhas? Eu costumo fazer isso mas me questiono quanto a necessidade disso.

Comment: @Articuno Pensei em usar `IllegalStateException` ou `NoSuchElementException`, mas ambas são `RuntimeException` e como tem que dar `catch` no menu para o programa não estourar e nesse caso específico (é raro, mas esse é um deles) é bom que o compilador force isso, então achei melhor ser uma `Exception` ao invés de `RuntimeException`.

Comment: O [Deque do java.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) usa `NoSuchElementException` em alguns métodos. Mas é um caso um pouco diferente, pois oferece métodos "seguros" e "inseguros" para acessar os elementos, como getFirst e peekFirst.

Comment: @VictorStafusa muito obrigada pelas dicas, isso realmente vai me ajudar nos desenvolvimentos futuros.

Comment: Agora eu precisaria saber a melhor forma de implementar algo de lambda e callback no código, para mim realmente lambda não está totalmente claro para pensar numa boa implementação.

Comment: @SabrinaB. Lambda é uma forma de implementar um callback. No entanto a abordagem que deve ser feita é a de ao encontrar-se um problema, buscar a melhor ferramenta para resolvê-lo. Tentar colocar lambda aí seria a abordagem oposta, a de a partir de uma ferramenta, tentar achar um problema que ela resolve, o que não dá muito certo. No entanto, uma situação (dentre várias possíveis outras) que naturalmente induz a necessidade de lambdas/callbacks seria a de ter *listeners* de eventos, então você pode procurar situações assim para aprender mais sobre lambdas e callbacks.