# Java: Problemas para utilizar expressões lambda em método listing com tipo genérico

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, genéricos

O problema seria que não consigo multiplicar as variáveis que retornam do listing utilizando o lambda (e*e), ele fica pedindo para criar um metodo listing utilizando object, mas to usando generics.
Agradeço qualquer contribuição.

```
public Element<T> listing() {
            Element<T> e = head;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Start listing... ");
            while (e != null) {
                System.out.println("Value: " + e.getValue());
                e = e.getNext();
            }
            System.out.println("End listing");
            System.out.println("");
            return e;

        }
```

Chamada

```
Deque<String> deque = new Deque<String>(); 
deque.addFirst("zero");
deque.addFirst("first");
deque.addFirst("secound");
deque.addFirst("third");
deque.addLast("fifth");

deque.listing((e)-> System.out.println(e*e));
```

Comment: Faltou dizer qual é o problema.

Comment: O método `listing` apresentado não recebe argumento, mas o uso dele em `Deque<T>` recebe um `Consumer<T>`. Qual o problema que você realmente está enfrentando?

Comment: @Piovezan: O problema seria que não consigo multiplicar as variáveis que retornam do listing utilizando o lambda (e*e), ele fica pedindo para criar um método listing utilizando object, mas to usando generics. Agradeço qualquer contribuição

Comment: A classe `Deque` foi você quem a definiu? Com aquele método `listing`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, ela que definiu, em uma outra pergunta aqui no site.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308221/64969

Comment: O problema de querer imprimir `e*e` é que isso não dá certo com generics. No caso estão sendo usadas strings, porém o Java não faz `"first" * "third"`, por exemplo. Acho que você precisa explicar melhor o que quer fazer para aí a gente tentar encontrar uma solução.

Comment: No Java o operador de multiplicação só funciona com tipos primitivos (números inteiros ou de ponto flutuante), e acredito que também com classes _wrappers_ como `Integer` ou `Double` (graças ao _autoboxing_).

Comment: ah entendi a mancada.                                                                             Então se eu mudasse para Deque<Integer> deque = new Deque<Integer>();  e adicionar em vez de string deque.addFirst(1);
   deque.addFirst(2);
   deque.addFirst(3);
   deque.addFirst(4);
   deque.addLast(5);                                                                   
 não teria problemas para utilizar o deque.listing((e)-> System.out.println(e*e)); ? @Piovezan

Comment: O método `listing` ainda não recebe um parâmetro, como um `Consumer<T>`

Comment: Obrigada ! deu certo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A versão final do código que fiz com as sugestões da **implementação da lista duplamente encadeada circular utilizando lambda e generics** (juntamente com a outra parte do [questionamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308221/64969)) joguei aqui neste repositório, caso possa ajudar alguém: https://github.com/sabrinabgbc/java/tree/master/data-structure/queue/deque-circular-queue